# Pivot table in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, pivot-table

i have created the pivot table using vb.net code

```
    pivotField1 = pivotTable.PivotFields(14)
    pivotField2 = pivotTable.PivotFields(15)
    pivotField3 = pivotTable.PivotFields(16)
    pivotField4 = pivotTable.PivotFields(17)
    pivotField5 = pivotTable.PivotFields(18)

    pivotField1.Orientation = XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlDataField
    pivotField2.Orientation = XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlDataField
    pivotField3.Orientation = XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlDataField
    pivotField4.Orientation = XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlDataField
    pivotField5.Orientation = XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlDataField
    pivotField1.Function = XlConsolidationFunction.xlSum
    pivotField2.Function = XlConsolidationFunction.xlSum
    pivotField3.Function = XlConsolidationFunction.xlSum
    pivotField4.Function = XlConsolidationFunction.xlSum
    pivotField5.Function = XlConsolidationFunction.xlSum
```

But it displays in pivot tables as Sum-Value in Rowlable but i want to ColumnLabel so please help....

Answer (score 0):

Use this... May help :)

```
Dim ptSigmaRow As PivotField
For Each ptSigmaRow In ptTable.RowFields
    Dim d As String = ptSigmaRow.Name
    If ptSigmaRow.Name = "Data" Then
         ptSigmaRow.Orientation = XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlColumnField
    End If
Next
```